# How to setup anonymous block with a callback function that returns data

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest, nsurl

I have an API class that I'm using to make url requests throughout my app, and I want to give it a function allows me to make an API request and interpret that data that is returned from the server.  So far, I've only been able to get it working by having a void function which returns successfully, but without the content that was returned from the server.

I'm using this to make an API request:

```
-(void)requestEndpoint:(NSString*)endpoint withParams:(NSDictionary*)params success:(void (^)(void))successBlock fail:(void (^)(void))failBlock
```

My problem is that ASIHTTP expects a ASIBasicBlock, of type `(void (^)(void))`.  How can I set the completion block to expect something that returns a string with the response returned from the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the block to have a return value, change the first void to NSString.

```
(NSString* (^)(void))
```

If you want the string passes as a parameter into the block, replace the second void with NSString

```
(void (^)(NSString* str))
```